# PHP update MySQL database on same page

Tags: php, mysql

I am wanting to create a PHP MySQL script that will display data and then allow the user to edit the data, but without having to leave the page in order to do so.

So is it possible to display the MySQL data in a form, allow the user to click on it and edit it (like a normal email form) and click a save button and have the data update.

I understand the save button will reload the same page, I just dont want the user to have to go to a different page to edit the data.

Comment: No need for Ajax, just a simple form that submits to the same PHP which handles both the display and the update.

Comment: For an absolutely no page reloads required approach, you will need to use AJAX. Otherwise stick with the suggestion from @alfasin

Comment: Don't forget to accept some answer by clicking the tick on the left ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just use

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

It's possible also without any reload - using JavaScript and AJAX. [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) makes usage of AJAX a lot simplier.

Comment: Could I just use the same update.php that I would have used anyways?

Comment: Yes, `action=""` means data will be send to the same page. On the update.php you can check by `if($_POST)` if the form has been sent.

Comment: @user1586258 yes, but after you update, you would need to print a redirect header - `header("Location: [pageYouWantToGoTo.php]");`. It's just more efficient to do all the processing on the same page.

Comment: @Matt it's not neccessary. depends on code you are using.

Comment: @PeterDraexDräxler I agree, but OP asked if he could use the original *update.php* which (I assume) is a separate file.

Comment: @Matt look at second part of the sentence "_that I would have used anyways_" :)

Comment: Ok, so I'll just tweak the update.php a little to receive the new data, update it and then put me back on the page again.
I'll mess with AJAX if the client wants it

Thanks guys!

Comment: @PeterDraexDräxler no part of that sentence implies one way or another whether *update.php* is the file on which the form exists, or if it is a separate file, but I think we understand each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 
   // now you know the form has been submitted 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you will not use java script( Ajax) you can use $_REQUEST .. and use meta to sending user to sql list page .**

for example :

```
<?php

if($_REQUEST['do']=="showform"){
///// Show insert form   
echo "<form action=\"test.php\" method=\"get\" enctype=\"text/plain\">


<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" />
<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"insert\" name=\"do\" />
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" />


</form> " ;

$sql=$db->query("select * from names order by id decs ");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    ///
    /// print your data 
    ///
}    

}

if($_REQUEST['do']=="insert"){

    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
    /// call your insert function here 
    /// for Example

  $sql=$db->query(" insert into names(name) values('$name')");

  if($sql){///  
   echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='1; URL=test.php?do=showform'>"; 
  } 
  else{

    echo "erorr";
  }

}




?>
```

This only method  with out java script I hope will be useful

Comment: You should never be using string interpolation in your SQL. You should be using placeholders to guarantee that your SQL is escaped properly.

Comment: MR.tadman thank u ,it's just simple example not perfect example .

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against posting your form to the page used to display the data. If the user hit his browser's refresh button, the form will be sent again which may do things you don't want.

Use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) : post your form to a page used to process it, then this page has to send a header to redirect to your display page.